# Display MediaLibraryPickerField in SummaryAdmin in module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have added a MediaLibraryPickerField to a content type in my migration using this code:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("MyPart",
    builder => builder.WithField("MyImage", 
        fieldBuilder => fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField")
                                    .WithDisplayName("My Image")));
```

This gives me a media library picker control in my edit view and works as expected.

When I display MyPart in my SummaryAdmin, Orchard tries to use the Image.SummaryAdmin.cshtml and errors out here because the `.As<MediaPart>` returns null:

```
var mediaPart = ((ContentItem)Model.ContentItem).As<MediaPart>();
```

Model.ContentItem is not a MediaPart, it is a MyType.  It does have an ImagePart attached to MyType.

Questions:

1. Why is the Image shape looking for a MediaPart
2. How can I inject the MediaPart as part of the Model? (should I?)
3. Should I be creating an alternate view here and drilling down to the correct part?
4. Am I completely missing how to use a MediaLibraryPickerField?

Comment: Can you add more details about what exactly you tried? In particular, I'm not sure what you mean by "when I display MyPart in my SummaryAdmin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{  
     var mediaPart= ((Orchard.MediaLibrary.Fields.MediaLibraryPickerField)Model.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "MyImage")).MediaParts;
}
```